# Google index on/off not working anymore

Tags: google

I'm using these two tags on a website, but they doesn't seem to work anymore?

```
Indexed by Google
<!--googleoff: index-->
Not indexed by Google
<!--googleon: index-->
Indexed by Google
```

When I search a page on Google and view the `Cached` version I can still see whats inside the tags?

Ealier when I was viewing a cached website the text inside the tags was not cached/indexed by Google..

Are the tags deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tags are for the Google Search Appliance, not generic searching from public search engines. As Google [tell us](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710):

> To prevent most search engine web crawlers from indexing a page on
>   your site, place the following meta tag into the  section of
>   your page:
>
> `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`
>
> To prevent only Google web crawlers from indexing a page:
>
> `<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">`

Note, this will apply to the whole page. The googleon/googleoff tags [are not supported by Google's web-search at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19489890/2123139).